# Why does LatticeReduce require integral or at least rational inputs?

Tags: linear-algebra, lattices

The function `LatticeReduce` in *Mathematica* implements the LLL algorithm. It requires the lattice basis to be described as integral or at least rational numbers.

Why so?

The LLL algorithm itself is not limited to rational numbers, right? Why cannot the input be like $\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: I have yet to see a variant of LLL that extends beyond Gaussian rationals.